# how to hide textarea value using jquery for tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide my textarea value in tinymce editor but it doesn't work .
so how to make it using jquery .

Html Code :

```
  <div class="top_attach_sub tiny_but" align="center">
                            <textarea id="flow_button_view" name="dessc_desk" class="social_text_area tiny_but_text" placeholder="What's on your mind?">
                            <span id="title_txt_bar">
                            What's on your mind?
                            </span>
                            </textarea>

                        </div>
```

Jquery :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


                var $title_bar = $("#title_txt_bar");





                tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea",
                menubar:false,
                statusbar: false,
                plugins: [
                     "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                     "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                     "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor table code"
               ],

               content_css: "css/content.css",
               toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link | preview fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | inserttable | code ", 
               style_formats: [
                    {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                    {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                    {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                    {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                    {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                    {title: 'Table styles'},
                    {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
                ],

                 init_instance_callback: function (editor) {

                        editor.on('focus', function (e) {
                          $title_bar.hide();
                        });

                      }


                 });
```

so when I click the textarea tinymce box than the value hide I need.

Thanks to all

Comment: Please explain in more detail what *"hide textarea value"* means? Not clear what you are asking

Comment: I set a value in textarea like What's on your mind? when I click the textarea box than I want to hide the text "What's on your mind?" that's all sir :)

Comment: But the original textarea is hidden completely when you use tinyMCE. It creates it's own elements. Do you mean when you focus on the editor?

Comment: I see that you have already a placeholder, so why do you add the same text in span tag ? Do you actually want to add a placeholder to tinymce ?